# Handling of block execution (block which saves image in core data) from queue when user logsout

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

**This is what I am doing in my project**
User does login with facebook, once successful login the app starts downloading of all images from sever in background queue. I have written the saving of image to core data in a block and submit the block to background queue so that main thread will be not be blocked.

**Problem:**
Once user does login, he goes to settings screen where he logs out of the app. At that point there might be blocks in the queue and they will be executing saving of the images to core data. My app crashes due to uncaught exception *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Object's persistent store is not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator.

When I log out I clear the persistent store and coordinator of the app. Those are global objects to the app. But I am not sure why this crash is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Are you cancelling all the pending loads at the same time?

Comment: Since blocks are submitted to queue for image fetching and saving into core data, how can these blocks can be cancelled or stopped from executing?

Comment: You should use an operation queue and / or have the blocks make a check to see if they should continue operation (like check current user and login status).

Comment: Exactly as@Wain says, use atomic properties and your blocks can first either check a single ivar flag (isCancelled) or user status to know whether to do work or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. The issue was due to clearing the store of the app when user taps on logs out. When it gets cleared there might be some blcoks in the queue which are still executing and when they try to save the image to core data, the app gets crashed. Now I have fixed this buy adding the clear store as a part of block and submitted to same queue so that the store gets cleared once all all blocks gets over from queue.